# Disable favorite tag highlighting for every tag in search

Tags: bug, search, new-nav, tag-watching

If you do a search for a single tag on your favorites list, it doesn't show the yellow background for any questions which have that tag (unless it has another of your favorite tags):
[image: No Background]

However, if I add an additional tag from my favorites list into the search, then every question will have the background:
[image: With Background]

If I start off searching for a single tag, and then add "or [favorite-tag-2]" to the search, then only the questions with tag2 show up with the yellow background. After switching to another tab and back, every question will show up with the favorite tag background, including the first tag which didn't have the highlighting before.

I feel like the only questions which should be emphasized are those with a tag which isn't in my search. I want to have a tab for questions asked in any of my favorite languages, but it's mildly annoying to see the entire page with that background. I'm torn on whether to tag this as a bug or a feature request, but since the behavior changes on reopening a tab when you use "or", it seems like a bug.

I've discovered that navigating directly to a page that has such a filter (eg. for me [Java and Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20and%20scala)) causes the highlighting to work correctly. But everything I've tried through the nav itself causes the problem. From the comments, this seems to vary between different people, but at least in my case it's 100% reproducible, and only stops upon refreshing the page.

After doing some more testing, the rules for what gets highlighted and what doesn't seem to be more-or-less arbitrary. If I have three of my favorite tags in the filter as "A or B and C", it will not highlight any questions who only have tag A, but will highlight anything containing B. Example:

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  For me it highlights the proper questions and ignores the others (this [picture](http://i.imgur.com/2VrXH9i.png) is using collapsed view, but the expanded view doesn't change that either).

Comment: @ryanyuyu How did you get to that page? I found that I can avoid the problem if I directly load a page with that search filter, but everything I've tried through the nav shows me the incorrect highlighting.

Comment: I finally was able to reproduce this (temporarily) by adding a new tab and adding the information.  But after clicking outside the search box (lose focus) and re-focusing it, the tag highlighting was fixed.  So at least for me, it seems to be a bad initial state that is fixed after other interaction with the page.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Odd. I can't seem to get it to go away at all. Regardless of what I do on the page after getting there (other than refreshing), it stay highlighted.

Comment: Huh.  I have no idea what's different.  At any rate, +1 since I was actually able to reproduce this (at least temporarily).

Comment: Same thing happens to me.